# Welche Stellung hat "heute" im Satz?

Tags: adverb, word-order

Welcher Satz ist richtig:

> Die Kinder sind fröhlich, weil die Ferien heute beginnen.

oder

> Die Kinder sind fröhlich, weil heute die Ferien beginnen.

Ich glaube beide sind richtig, weil ich gelernt habe, dass das Subjekt im Nebensatz zuerst steht, aber ich habe auch gelernt, dass Temporaladverbien als erste stehen können.

Comment: Ich glaube, dass der erste Satz richgig ist. D.h. wenigstens der erste Satz..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Du hast recht: Beide Sätze sind richtig.

Allerdings liegt der Fokus beim Satz

> Die Kinder sind fröhlich, weil die Ferien heute beginnen.

eher auf der Tatsache, dass sie eben genau **heute** beginnen. Durch diesen Satzbau wirkt es für mich als Leser so, als sei das Temporaladverb der wichtige Teil.

> Die Kinder sind fröhlich, weil heute die Ferien beginnen.

ist aber ebenso richtig.

Ich finde die zweite Version (… weil heute …) sogar eleganter und angenehmer.

Genauso gut könntest du auch

> Die Kinder sind fröhlich, dass heute die Ferien beginnen.

sowie

> Die Kinder sind fröhlich, dass die Ferien heute beginnen.

schreiben, allerdings würde sich durch das „dass“ der Sinn etwas verschieben. Die Ferien sind nicht mehr reiner Auslöser der Fröhlichkeit („weil“ … „beginnen“), sondern tragen „nur“ zur Fröhlichkeit bei („fröhlich, dass … beginnen“).

Comment: Ich glaube das kommt auf die Betonung an. Ich kann den Satz "..., weil die Ferien heute beginnen." ohne Probleme so lesen, dass der Fokus auf Ferien liegt. Dass du den Fokus auf heute siehst, liegt daran, dass du im Geiste dementsprechend betonst. Der Satzbau allein reicht meiner Ansicht nach nicht aus... manchmal ja, aber nicht hier.

Answer (score 1):

Statt mit Ferien vergleiche folgende Beispiele:

> Ich bin froh, dass heute das Open-Air-Konzert stattfindet. Denn sonst hätte ich heute nichts vor.
>
> Ich bin froh, dass das Open-Air-Konzert heute stattfindet - und nicht etwa gestern, als so schlechtes Wetter war.

Comment: Du kannst die zweiten Sätze jeweils austauschen. Dabei musst Du auch die Betonung ändern, aber dann ergibt sich auch der jeweils andere Sinn.

Answer (score 0):

Beide Sätze sind richtig. Die Bedeutung ist nur ganz leicht unterschiedlich. Das liegt nämlich daran, was als erstes erwähnt wird. Das Wichtige wird meistens zuerst erwähnt. Das würde man beim Aussprechen erkennen, je nach Betonung.
Im ersten Satz wird der Fokus eher auf "Ferien" gelegt. Die Ferien beginnen heute, wie schön, endlich kein Schulstress mehr.
Im zweiten Satz, wird "heute" in den Vordergrund gerückt. Endlich beginnen die Ferien! Heute ist es so weit, und die Kinder müssen nicht mehr sehnsuchtsvoll warten.

Theoretisch kann man den Fokus aber auch umgekehrt legen. Aber dann betont man beim Aussprechen genau das Wort, um das es einen geht. Dann würde man beim ersten Satz das Wort "heute" betonen und im zweiten Satz die "Ferien".
Beides also möglich. (Soviel von einem Muttersprachler).

Comment: Sehe ich genau andersherum.